# With templatetag raises error

Tags: python, django

I want to define a variable if a condition is met:

```
    {% if order_item.status.ordering >= 60 and is_client %}
        {% with readonly=1 %}
    {% else %}
        {% with readonly=0 %}
    {% endif %}

    ...some code

    {% endwith %}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Invalid block tag: 'else', expected 'endwith'
```

How can I fix this bug in django?

Comment: Have you actually read the error? It's fairly clear imho ;) For your reference, here's the manual on using the `with` template tag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: The -1 isn't mine btw ;)

Comment: @WoLpH understood — why can't I define the {% with %} tag here ... run some other code ... and then close the {% endwith %} at the end?

Comment: You can, but just like html you have to open and close tags in order. If you open a with tag you can put a lot of stuff within that tag, but it has to be closed before you close a parent tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it's better to add a `readonly` property/method to your `order_item.status`.

Alternatively you could also try a templatefilter or templatetag.

Comment: `u'with' received an invalid token: u'>='`

Comment: Hmmm... Jinja only I guess :( In that case you could write your own template tag or filter to do this...

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make any sense, first you should learn the with syntax. You have opened it twice and closed once and you don't have any useful code inside with.

Comment: Wouldn't the if statement make it such that it's only opened once?

Comment: Each time you open a tag you have to close it! It doesn't depend on logical conditions (if/else). It's a matter of syntax!